# How to post generic type in jersey?

Tags: java, json, rest, generics, jersey-2.0

--------------Generic Type------------------

```
public class Pair<KT, VT> {
    private KT key;
    private VT value;

    public Pair() {
    }

    public Pair(KT key, VT value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

-------------Restful API------------

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestApi {
    @GET
    @Path("/query")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Pair query(@DefaultValue("0") @QueryParam("key") int key) {
        return new Pair(key, "value:" + key);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String create(Pair<Integer, String> pair){
        return "put success : " + pair.toString();
    }
}
```

-------------Problem--------------

Response of GET : http://localhost:8080/api/test/query is:

`{"key":{"type":"int","value":0},"value":{"type":"string","value":"value:0"}}`

But, when I post the same json to POST : http://localhost:8080/api/test/post with "Content-Type: application/json" header, exception occurs:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to post a generic type object?

---------------pom.xml------------------

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jetty.version>9.0.6.v20130930</jetty.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: how are you posting? are you providing the "Content-Type: application/json" header?

Comment: Yes! I have set "Content-Type: application/json" header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not be the correct response to the GET request

```
{"key":{"type":"int","value":0},"value":{"type":"string","value":"value:0"}}
```

It should be

```
{"key":0,"value":"value:0"}
```

This is just one of the many perils of working with [MOXy](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.moxy), which is the default JSON provider for Jersey (in Glassfish). If you use [Jackson](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson) instead, you should see the correct behavior.

To use Jackson, you can either just disable MOXy (which prevents Jackson from being registered) by setting the property [`ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23.1/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE) to `true`. Or you can add The Jackson dependency, and then register the `JacksonFeature` with the application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

After making the change, it should work properly for both the GET and POST request.

---

### UPDATE

Test source. When you run the test, you should also see in the logs the correct output from the request, which just returns the same pair as posted.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Entity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Required dependencies for test
 * 
 *  <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
 *      <version>2.23</version>
 *  </dependency>
 *  <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
 *      <version>2.23</version>
 *  </dependency>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class JacksonGenericTest extends JerseyTest {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Pair<K, V> {

        private K key;
        private V value;

        public Pair() {
        }

        public Pair(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(K key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" + "key=" + key + ", value=" + value + '}';
        }
    }

    @Path("test")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public static class TestResource {

        @POST
        public Pair create(Pair<Integer, String> pair) {
            return pair;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class)
                // not required here since we don't have MOXy on the classpath,
                // but in Glassfish, you should make sure to register it
                // so it disables MOXy, since Glassfish has MOXy on the classpath.
                .register(JacksonFeature.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }
    
    private final String jsonData = "{\"key\":100,\"value\":\"value:100\"}";

    @Test
    public void postTest() {
        final Response response = target("test")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.json(jsonData));
        final Pair<Integer, String> pair = response.readEntity(
                new GenericType<Pair<Integer, String>>(){});
        assertThat(pair.getKey(), is(100));
        assertThat(pair.getValue(), is("value:100"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried with jersey-media-json-jackson dependency, It just doesn't work, and return {}, rather than {"key":0,"value":"value:0"}.It seems that I should not return customized generic type except for List type.

Comment: I actually tested before posting this amd it worked fine for me. Both GET and POST worked as expected

Comment: Hey peeskillet, I just attached my pom.xml, and I use glassfish as web server. Wish your help.

Comment: It will be better if you post your test source:-)

Comment: Yes! It worked, though I don't even know why. I think I have done nothing, I put your test code into my project and test, then my code work too! Thanks!